# Trying to use the same function on individual cards

Tags: javascript

i have these 3 cards where i have the main body of text hidden. i want to be able to click on each individual button and it shows the details for that card. but every time i do get the JavaScript to work each button will only open the first cards hidden text. i was hiding the text by setting a max-height so i could use transition on the height.

any help would be appreciated

```js
var cardBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.cardBtn');
var cardDetails = document.querySelectorAll(".card-details");

cardBtns.forEach(function(cardBtn) {
  cardBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cardDetails.classList.toggle('card-open');
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="card1" id="card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <div class="card-heading">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card2" id="card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <div class="card-heading">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card3" id="card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <div class="card-heading">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        **<button class="cardBtn">show more</button>**
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I feel like the JavaScript is wrong, I've tried many alternatives

Comment: where is css of this code snippt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close:

```
var cardBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.cardBtn');
var cardDetails = document.querySelectorAll(".card-details");

cardBtns.forEach(function (cardBtn, index) {
  cardBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    cardDetails[index].classList.toggle('card-open');
  });

});
```

The problem was inside the event handler, bacause by calling `cardDetails` you deal with an array of elements, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You had all 3 with id='card' so I made that a class.

The way you can find the relative 'card-detail' is through capturing the event (e) and finding the closest 'card' class, then querySelector finding the associated 'card-body'

The transition is a css rule, and with height the way to do it is to work with `max-height` - setting the 'open' max-height to be larger than the actual.

```js
var cardBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.cardBtn');
var cardDetails = document.querySelectorAll(".card-details");

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  cardBtns.forEach(cardBtn => {
    cardBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.target.closest('.card').querySelector('.card-body').classList.toggle('card-open');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.card {}

.card-body {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
}

.card-body.card-open {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card1 card">
  <div class="card-details">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card2 card">
  <div class="card-details">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card3 card">
  <div class="card-details">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      **<button class="cardBtn">show more</button>**
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it:

```html
 <div class="card1" id="card">
   <div class="card-details">
     <div class="card-heading">
       <h3>Heading</h3>
       <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
     </div>
     <div class="card-body d-none">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card2" id="card">
   <div class="card-details">
     <div class="card-heading">
       <h3>Heading</h3>
       <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
     </div>
     <div class="card-body d-none">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card3" id="card">
   <div class="card-details">
     <div class="card-heading">
       <h3>Heading</h3>
       <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
     </div>
     <div class="card-body d-none">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <script>
   var cardBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.cardBtn');

   cardBtns.forEach(function(cardBtn) {
     cardBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
       let cardDetails = cardBtn.closest('.card-details');
       let cardBody = cardDetails.getElementsByClassName('card-body')[0];
       if (cardBody.classList.contains('d-none')) {
         cardBody.classList.remove('d-none');
         cardBody.classList.add('d-block');
         cardBtn.textContent = 'Show Less';
       } else {
         cardBody.classList.remove('d-block');
         cardBody.classList.add('d-none');
         cardBtn.textContent = 'Show more';
       }
     });
   });

 </script>

 <style>
   .d-none {
     display: none;
   }

   .d-block {
     display: block;
   }

 </style>
```

JS fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5sqkdp0x/

Answer (score 0):

I would just add one event listener for the entire page. I don't know how many cards you will end up having, but if you got 10.000 of them, it will take time to add them all.

Also, id on elements should be unique, so remove all occurrences of `id="card"` because they serves almost no purpose.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let element = event.target;
  
  if (element.classList.contains('cardBtn')) {
    let cardHeadingEl = element.parentNode;
    let cardDetailsEl = cardHeadingEl.parentNode;
    cardDetailsEl.classList.toggle('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.card-body {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  transition: opacity 300ms, max-height 400ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.card-details.open > .card-body {
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="card1" id="card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <div class="card-heading">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card2" id="card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <div class="card-heading">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <button class="cardBtn">show more</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card3" id="card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <div class="card-heading">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        **<button class="cardBtn">show more</button>**
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minima eaque rem sapiente omnis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```